# How to query Prolog through Javascript?

Tags: javascript, prolog, swi-prolog, wordnet

I am using SWI-Prolog to query the WordNet Database. I now need to build a HTML interface that will accept a word from the user and query it against the db.

How can I write a JS code that will send the word to Prolog wrapped in a query and how can I retrieve the results in meaningful variables that I can display back in the webpage?

Comment: did you check http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/package/http.html ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will probably want to use the HTTP server support that comes with SWI-Prolog. Use Ajax and JSON to interchange queries and results, there's a page in the online documentation that will get you started: [http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section(2,'5',swi('/doc/packages/http.html'))](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%275%27,swi%28%27/doc/packages/http.html%27%29%29)

If you don't know [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) already, you should check it out. It will be very easy to get the Ajax calls working, and it also contains support for handling JSON easily.

If you want to use some other web server, say Apache, there's a HowTo in the documentation for that as well. Good luck!

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for. I will report here again of my progress after I go through that document. Thanks.